# CentOS - Wrong automatic ifconfig broadcast address

Tags: networking, centos, broadcast, subnet, ifconfig

Running a Centos 5.11 machine with two network cards.
One is facing the internal network (private IP), the other the Internet (public IP).

Because we had some issues lately with it (ARP collision - but that's not the point here!), I started verifying its config. And I find out the broadcast set for the public IP is wrong.

IP is xxx.xxx.xxx.25
Subnet is 255.255.255.240
So basically we should have:

```
 Network xxx.xxx.xxx.16
 First IP xxx.xxx.xxx.17
 Last IP xxx.xxx.xxx.30
 Broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.31
```

But the broadcast is automatically set to last host xxx.xxx.xxx.30
If I change it using command line, it is reseted back to the same IP once I do a service network restart...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to edit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 for the broadcast to stick to what I wanted.